# Swift, Protocols and Generics in Genetic Algorithm

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to switch from Java to Swift and improve my programming skills in this language.

However, I have some difficulties understanding how generics works in Swift after a study of:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html

I have started to write a genetic algorithm by writing some protocols.

```
protocol Point : Equatable {
    var identifier: String { get }
    var x: Double { get }
    var y: Double { get }
    func distance<P : Point>(to point: P) -> Double
}

protocol Individual {
    associatedtype P : Point
    var fitness: Double { get }
    var chromosomes: [P] { get }
}
```

and now I want to make a struct which conforms to the Individual protocol.

The only try that compiles is

```
struct Route : Individual {
    typealias P = City;
    var fitness: Double { 0.0 }
    var chromosomes: [City]
}
```

However, I want to make Route as much as generic, therefore I don't want to tell that it uses City as implementation of Point. I want that Route knows that it works on array of objects which conforms to Point protocol.

I'd appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest adding a `Self` requirement on the `distance(to:)` method. `Self` just tells the compiler that the paremeter is the same type as the conforming type.

```
protocol Point : Equatable {
    var identifier: String { get }
    var x: Double { get }
    var y: Double { get }
    func distance(to point: Self) -> Double
}
```

So, in your `City` struct `point` must also be of type `City`.

```
struct City: Point {
    var identifier: String
    var x: Double
    var y: Double

    func distance(to point: City) -> Double {
        return .zero
    }
}
```

You can make your `Route` struct more flexible by adding a generic parameter that also satisfies the associated type requirement imposed by the `Individual` protocol.

```
struct Route<P: Point>: Individual {
    var fitness: Double { 0.0 }
    var chromosomes: [P]
}
```

To instantiate a `Route`:

```
var cityRoute = Route<City>(chromosomes: [])
```

Comment: Awesome. It works as I wanted. Thank you. I didn't know that I can use Self as type.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of class that implements a specific protocol, so for example in this case you will have:

```
 struct Route: Individual {
    typealias P = City;
    var fitness: Double { 0.0 }
    var chromosomes: [Point]
}
```

and you can call all the protocol methods.

Comment: `var chromosomes: [Point]` The compiler says: "Protocol 'Point' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements". I was thinking about something like this before.